# difference between rows until difference row came

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
tctid   owner       Mindate
1165267 Unassigned  2016-11-01 16:53:19
1165267 John        2016-11-02 10:54:06
1165267 Harry       2016-11-02 17:02:38
1181499 Priority    2016-11-02 18:28:18
1181499 Abraham     2016-11-02 18:36:10
1181499 John        2016-11-10 01:01:50
1181499 Abdullah    2016-11-13 11:03:36
1181499 Harry       2016-11-17 19:25:31
1183682 Unassigned  2016-11-03 19:07:00
1183682 Harry       2016-11-03 19:09:57
1183682 John        2016-11-03 19:20:39
1183682 Harry       2016-11-08 13:15:57
1183682 John        2016-11-08 14:08:46
1183682 David       2016-11-19 09:45:31
1183682 IT          2016-12-13 22:06:50
1183682 John        2016-12-14 20:19:37
1183682 Harry       2016-12-14 22:12:03
```

Now i want to find the difference between rows until next unique ticket id came. I am looking for this out put

```
tctid   owner         Mindate              Diff in Day:Hour:Min
1165267 Unassigned    2016-11-01 16:53:19   0:18:0
1165267 John          2016-11-02 10:54:06   0:6:8
1165267 Harry         2016-11-02 17:02:38   For Last entry no calculation 
1181499 Priority      2016-11-02 18:28:18   0:0:7
1181499 Abraham       2016-11-02 18:36:10   7:6:25
1181499 John          2016-11-10 01:01:50   3:10:1
1181499 Abdullah      2016-11-13 11:03:36   4:8:21
1181499 Harry         2016-11-17 19:25:31   For Last entry no calculation 
1183682 Unassigned    2016-11-03 19:07:00   0:0:2
1183682 Harry         2016-11-03 19:09:57   0:0:10
1183682 John          2016-11-03 19:20:39   4:17:55
1183682 Harry         2016-11-08 13:15:57   0:0:52
1183682 John          2016-11-08 14:08:46   10:19:36
1183682 David         2016-11-19 09:45:31   24:12:21
1183682 IT            2016-12-13 22:06:50   0:22:12
1183682 John          2016-12-14 20:19:37   0:1:52
1183682 Harry         2016-12-14 22:12:03   For Last entry no calculation
```

and for last entry of the same ticket no difference needed.

here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30a42/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, in MySQL you must use CASE (not IF) in Select Query (I mistaken with Oracle)

```
select t.*, (
case when((
select count(t2.tctid) 
from tickets t2 
where t2.tctid = t.tctid and t.mindate < t2.mindate 
order by t2.tctid, t2.mindate ASC) > 1) 
         THEN ( select TIMEDIFF(t2.mindate,t.mindate) 
               from tickets t2 
               where t2.tctid = t.tctid and t.mindate < t2.mindate 
               order by t2.tctid, t2.mindate ASC LIMIT 1 ) 
ELSE 'For Last entry no calculation' END ) as diff
from tickets t order by t.tctid, t.mindate ASC;
```

Ok I try it i my DB, but you have invalid time format for your insert (time have same zeros), please try this code, and change it by your needs. For compare dates use maybe != or something to comparing to dates in MySql if this wersion doesnt work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for current time difference compared to the previous ticket, this difference do you want to write to the current? Try USE [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

And in each new insert select time data from last ticketid and use TIMEDIFF, this value save to the inserted(new value) and column name previsous_diff or some like that

if you want when creating a new ticket add the time difference to the previous ticket process will be complicated and the question is whether it is necessary ?

Comment: I want find the diff between two rows. example: the first two rows are  1165267 Unassigned  2016-11-01 16:53:19
1165267 John             2016-11-02 10:54:06  and ticket id is same. so in that case i just want to find the difference between them which is 0:18:0  but for 3rd and 4th row the ticket id are different so no calculation is there @Jan Sršeň

Comment: I understand, but how do you know then ticket ID is last (if you use inserting new tickets in this case, if not use inserting this question is not important). You use only Mysql or some programing language like PHP or ASP.NET ?

For my opinion, in your main select use for time_diff_calculation (subselect) wher you fine ticket with same id without actual selected time and largertime then actual selected and count number of subcolums, if they are larger then 1 -> you know then row is not last, and use select where use timediff

Comment: you are right. new row can be inserted i can also use php. But is there any option in mysql to find my desire output? can you give me a fiddle or some thing so that i can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you need edit existing data, or only calculate it direcly use hava 2 options:

1. Use mysql (DR respond is slow)
2. Use PHP

For MySql use something like that:

```
select 
t.*,
 (
   select 
    IF count(t2.tctid) > 1 THEN
      (
        // You must select 1 value from previous select query
        select TIMEDIFF(t2.mindate,t.mindate)
      )
    ELSE
     'For Last entry no calculation '
    END IF 
   from tickets t2 
   where t2.tctid=t.tctid and t.mindate <> t2.mindate 
   order by t2.tctid, t2.mindate ASC
 ) 
from tickets t order by t.tctid, t.mindate ASC;
```

Comment: can you please explain '// You must select 1 value from previous select query'